# Can a cell review comment be referenced with the cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I understand you can reference cell values using `[Sheetname]![Cell]` which creates a read-only link to the referenced cell value.

Is there a way to also reference the review comment attached to a cell in and have it pulled through along with the value?

The only option I've been able to find is to copy the original cell and then use paste-special in the second worksheet to bring over the review comment attached.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this VBA code in a module in Excel (open Visual Basic in Excel, click on Insert and choose module, and paste the following:
**Public Function CELCOM(rgCELL As Range) As String

On Error GoTo NO_COMMENT

CELCOM = "Comment in " & _

rgCELL.Address(False, False) & _

":= " & _

rgCELL.Comment.Text

NO_COMMENT:

End Function**
If B1 has a comment that you need to copy to another cell, then in the the cell where you want to  copy the comment write:
`=celcom(B1)`
or
`=celcom(sheet1!B1)`
Celcom became a function you can use.

Comment: This is close to what I'm after - But I'm looking to apply the review comment to a cell with a value in, so there would be the referenced value in the cell and the referenced comment as well (red triangle in cell corner, comment appears on mouse-over)

Comment: It is not applicable because =celcom(...) is the formula in the cell, we cannot put value and this formula in the same cell

Comment: you can put it in an adjacent cell